# Can't install alongside Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside my 64-bit Windows 7, but when I used the installation DVD the only option that showed up was to replace Windows with it. Does anyone know why the option to install alongside my original OS does not appear?

[image]

It is partitioned into my main drive and a backup drive. I should add that I had Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine before, but I had to uninstall it due to being unable to enter text when prompted for a password to install anything. This is the same setup I had before I installed the original Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you shrink your Win7 drive?

Answer (score 2):

I see there is one more option named "Something Else". You could click on this and create a new partition for your Ubuntu.

More information could be found in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ

Nam

Comment: your link may answer the question precisely , but please include either complete answer or part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got Ubuntu 64 bit installed along side windows. Here is how i did it;
enter bios and disable fast boot and turn off UEFI secure boot. Save then exit. do restart and reenter bios and change boot order to the non UEFI optical drive. If windows is already installed proceed to install Ubuntu. the option to install along side windows will now show up.